# Zendesk and Salesforce sync

Tags: zendesk

If am trying to sync contacts/leads with Zendesk using Salesforce. I am getting the reply like this. I don't know how to clear this issue.

> Hi User Admin,
> There was a problem syncing with Zendesk, Error Details : Insert failed. First exception on row 950; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email: invalid email address: "legal "@acsports.com: [Email]
> 1 out of 1000 records synchronized successfully. 
>  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies right there in the error message. The email address field you are trying to sync is "legal[space]"@acsports.com which isn't a valid email address.